# Perl parse links from HTML Table

Tags: html, perl, parsing

I'm trying to get links from table in HTML. By using [HTML::TableExtract](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTML%3a%3aTableExtract), I'm able to parse table and get text (i.e. Ability, Abnormal in below example) but cannot get link that involves in the table. For example,

```
<table id="AlphabetTable">
   <tr>     
   <td>
    <a href="/cate/A/Ability">Ability</a> <span class="count">2650</span>
   </td>  
   <td>
    <a href="/cate/A/Abnormal">Abnormal</a> <span class="count">26</span>
   </td>
</table>
```

Is there a way to get link using HTML::TableExtract ? or other module that could possibly use in this situation. Thanks

part of my code:

```
$mech->get($link->url());
$te->parse($mech->content);

foreach $ts ($te->tables){
   foreach $row ($ts->rows){
       print @$row[0];     #it only prints text part
                           #but I want its link 
   }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[HTML::LinkExtor](http://p3rl.org/HTML%3a%3aLinkExtor), passing the extracted table text to its parse method.

```
my $le = HTML::LinkExtor->new();

foreach $ts ($te->tables){
    foreach $row ($ts->rows){
        $le->parse($row->[0]);
        for my $link_tag ( $le->links ) {
            my ($tag, %links) = @$link_tag;
            # next if $tag ne 'a'; # exclude other kinds of links?
            print for values %links;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you tell me a bit more specifically with the example that I mentioned?

Comment: Do you really just want the first td on each row?

Answer (score 4):

Use `keep_html` option in the constructor.

> **keep_html**
>
> Return the raw HTML contained in the cell, rather than just the visible text. Embedded tables are not retained in the HTML extracted from a cell. Patterns for header matches must take into account HTML in the string if this option is enabled. This option has no effect if extracting into an element tree structure.

```
$te = HTML::TableExtract->new( keep_html => 1, headers => [qw(field1 ... fieldN)]);
```